# ¿Cómo importar un variable que esta dentro de una función en otro archivo Python?

Tags: python, python-import, qt-designer

Estoy haciendo un pequeño programa tipo contactos, cuando el usuario digite las especificaciones del contacto, **quiero que se muestre en una tabla que este en otro archivo** `py.`. El problema es cuando quiero importar las varibles de dichos datos (*introduce_producto*, *introduce_precio*, *introduce_marca*), ya que dichas variables están dentro de una función, por lo tanto cuando importo el archivo donde estan las variables no las detecta, lanzando este error:

`NameError: name 'introduce_producto' is not defined.`

¿ALGUIEN SABE COMO PUEDO MOSTRAR LAS VARIABLES EN OTRO ARCHIVO SIN MOSTRAR EL ERROR?

**¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo mostrar las variables en otro archivo?**

Este es el archivo donde el usuario digita:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets

qtCreatorFile = "preset-añadir_productos.ui" # Nombre del archivo aquí.
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton_agree.clicked.connect(self.boton_agree)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.setFixedSize(301, 370)

    def boton_agree(self):
        introduce_producto = self.Inp_nombre_de_producto.text()
        introduce_precio = self.Inp_nombre_de_precio.text() 
        introduce_marca = self.Inp_nombre_de_marca.text()
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app =  QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Y este el segundo archivo, donde quiero que se muestren las variables

```
import sys
import os
from preañapro import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets

qtCreatorFile = "productos_p2.ui" # Nombre del archivo aquí.
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton_plus.clicked.connect(self.boton_plus)
        self.pushButton_plus.clicked.connect(self.boton_agree)
        self.pushButton_edit.clicked.connect(self.boton_edit)
        self.pushButton_delete.clicked.connect(self.boton_remove)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.setFixedSize(450, 700)
        
    def boton_plus(self):
        cmd = 'preañapro.py'
        os.system(cmd)
        
    def boton_edit(self):
        cmd = 'preset-editar_productos.py'
        os.system(cmd)
        
    def boton_remove(self):
        cmd = 'preset-remove_productos.py'
        os.system(cmd)
        
    def boton_agree(self):
        print(introduce_producto)
        print(introduce_precio)
        print(introduce_marca)
        

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app =  QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Enserio, gracias si responden. Cracks!

Comment: El problema es que cada uno de esos archivos da lugar a una aplicación separada en tiempo de ejecución ¿no? O sea, no se trata que desde un script hagas un import del otro y tengas una sola aplicación, sino que cada script se ejecuta separadamente y da lugar a dos aplicaciones. Si esto es así, la única forma que tienes es que estas aplicaciones se comuniquen entre sí de alguna forma, por ejemplo escribiendo los datos en un fichero o base de datos del que la otra pueda leerlos.

Comment: Si se trata de una sola aplicación, declara las variables globales en el módulo fuente y luego los importas donde quieras usarlas. Si son dos aplicaciones separadas, graba las variables en un archivo o base de datos y luego las lees en otro archivo.

Comment: Las variables locales a una función sólo existen mientras la función ejecuta. Esa es la idea de variables locales.